# Correct Memory Management for [string UTF8String]

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring

I'm somewhat new to objective-c and I'm not sure what the correct memory management for this code is.

```
const unsigned char * data =(const unsigned char *) [string UTF8String];
```

When I call free on data I get an error. Do I need to clean up after this call?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No. "UTF8String" does not contain the words `alloc`, `copy`, `retain`, or `create`. Thus, you're not responsible for that memory.

Note that if you want that data to stick around after `string` is released, you should copy it; by the contract, you're not responsible for that memory, but you are also not guaranteed that it will last beyond the scope of the object that gave it to you.

Comment: That C string gets freed when the NSString is deallocated. (Or the internal state of the object changes.)

Comment: This is dangerous advice. A lot of methods that deal with C pointers do require you to free the memory. The alloc copy retain rule is for objects.

Comment: @Chuck: I've added a note about "create", which would take care of the Core Foundation objects as well. Can you give an example of a method that would require the caller to free the memory that is not covered by that rule?

Comment: It is safe to release the string object because data is a pointer to a new memory location storing the characters returned by UTF8String. The data variable is not an id type. It will not respond to objective-c messages.

Comment: It's also helpful to know that even for ObjC objects, there are exceptions to the memory management rules. These will be noted in the documentation. Eg. see NSPropertyListSerialization's -dataFromPropertyList:format:errorDescription:

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to `free` it.

In Cocoa, if a method does not contain the words `alloc`, `init`, or `copy`, you do not own the object that is returned from said method.

`-UTF8String` actually **points** to the `cstring` representation of the `NSString` object you are calling it on. When the object's state changes, the `UTF8String` also changes.

Comment: There is no object returned from this method so the memory management rules for objects are irrelevant.

Comment: I always thought what happens is the string is converted to an NSData object with `-dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding` and then the the result is the `bytes` method from that `NSData` object. I've never bothered to try and look under the hood so I'm likely wrong about this.

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#jumpTo_128), it is automatically freed the same way an autoreleased object would be.

Answer (score 0):

technically speaking, free() is used to remove memory allocated using malloc() from the heap.
malloc() was not used to allocate the memory. remember that objective-c is c with extensions.
the data variable will remain in memory based on the c language 'scoping' rules.